# How do I render pre compressed .gz assets in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, static, render, webrick

I have a pre compressed `.gz` file that I want to render in a view.

So first off my config is set to `config.serve_static_files = true` so we shouldn't need something like nginx in front to serve the view.

Basically my problem comes when trying to render the file

```
render file: '/public/assets/bomb-html-char-X-1G.html.gz'
```

The error I get is as follows:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Your template was not saved as valid UTF-8. Please either specify UTF-8 as the encoding for your template in your text editor, or mark the template with its encoding by inserting the following as the first line of the template:

# encoding: <name of correct encoding>.

The source of your template was:

��@��Mk�@�s�+�=�mœ�
                       Yw�Z7��q�ݠI$�*�{��C�y|�2����/�d�����,�6�z�ϒ����,OᰎU�|��0�]]��\�N�
�6e�}���2��Pu���z��_�<�:�u����M�w�Cq���}o./߾
��H�X�q���_�}���U¾�<=�c_öy�/VOV���<$����S�T�/�C=�������u;��s
```

If I read the file in irb and check the encoding i get:

```
 => #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

If anyone wants to take a look at the file it can be found here:

[double comppressed version of the html.gz file](ftp://ftp.aerasec.de/pub/advisories/decompressionbombs/html/bomb-html-char-X-1G.html.gz.zip)

[instructions and password for unpacking](ftp://ftp.aerasec.de/pub/advisories/decompressionbombs/html/README_IMPORTANT_BEFORE_DOWNLOADING)

**NB: this is a HTML Decompression bomb (but I don't think this should affect it to much)**

Comment: Are you trying to allow download of the .gz file or trying to render it as a template?

Comment: you should use `send_file` instead of `render file`

Comment: I am still trying to render the file similar to: http://www.aerasec.de/security/advisories/html-bomb/bomb-html-char-X-1k

Comment: That page is not rendering the file.  It's just showing a visual representation of the number of characters in the file.

Comment: Actually if you look at the extracted version of the file you will get https://gist.github.com/whithajess/8c07c6f8a97c1f030569 so yes it is rendering the file. If you want to confirm this you can check here: http://www.aerasec.de/security/advisories/html-bomb/